# Change CollectionView EmptyView Text Color

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to change a CollectionView's EmptyView Text's font color. It seems to automatically change from black to white when switching between the native device's Light theme and Dark theme. TextColor is not an attribute, unfortunately.

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms, I'd like to apologize, first, if I haven't displayed enough code, please let me know if there's anything else you need.

My code is located in the AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HeightRequest="{Binding ShellHeight}" 
              ColumnSpacing="0" 
              RowSpacing="0" 
              RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto" 
              ColumnDefinitions="45, Auto">

            <CollectionView 
                   Margin="15,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding ShellModelList}" 
                   SelectionMode="Single" 
                   EmptyView="No items to display" //<-- trying to change this text's color
                   SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged">                   

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>                                                                                                                                                            
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="1" 
                              RowSpacing="10" 
                              ColumnDefinitions="25, Auto" 
                              RowDefinitions="35">

                              <Image Grid.Column="0">
                                  <Image.Source>
                                      <FontImageSource  
                                           x:Name="imgMenuItem" 
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource NextupFont}" 
                                           Glyph="{Binding IconName}" 
                                           Color="{StaticResource NuCyanBlue}" 
                                           Size="8" />
                                  </Image.Source>
                              </Image>
                             
                            <Label x:Name="lblMenuItem" 
                                   Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                   Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                   TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={DynamicResource NuCyanBlue}, Dark={DynamicResource NuBlack}}" 
                                   FontSize="12" 
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </Grid>            
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
```

[image: "No Items to Display" is black]

[image: "No Items To Display" is white]

Comment: The EmptyView property also can be set to a view, you can custom the label there. For more information, please read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/emptyview#display-views-when-data-is-unavailable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think what you should be doing is creating your custom EmptyView.

```
                    <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                    <StackLayout
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="18"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="No items to display" />
                      </StackLayout>
                   </CollectionView.EmptyView>
```

Good luck! feel free to get back if you have any queries.

Comment: Bravo! Your answer, alone, has taught me a great deal more about xamarin and xaml! I'm starting to get a better understanding of it now. Thank you again!

Comment: Happy to help :)